# validateUsername does not exist

Tags: laravel

when i am tried to add one text field which is called username for registration in laravel it says "Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateUsername does not exist.

i am trying to be change the datatype of the column but still does not give any other response

{{ __('username') }}

                            
                                

                                @error('username')
                                    
                                        **{{ $message }}**
                                    
                                @enderror

Comment: where is your form? how are you validating form values?

Comment: Please edit your question and show us your validation code.

Comment: my form  is as I described above the form or register.blade.php for username is in the above so

Comment: the validation is laravel have its own validation in controllers Directory  of the laravel module

Comment: laravel default auth scaffolding does not have a username. so whatever you have tried add it in the question. otherwise its not possible to help.

Comment: If you have changed the `validator()` function in the `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php` show us the code please.

Comment: 'username' => ['required', 'string', 'username'],

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the validator method creator on a type that it doesn't know anything about. I'm guessing that you took something like:

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
    ]);
}
```

and copied the email line and replaced 'email' with 'username' in two places, yielding something like this:

```
    protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'username' => ['required', 'string', 'username', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
    ]);
```

}

the problem is that the second 'email' isn't doing the same thing that the first one is. The first 'email' is your field name. The second one, however, is a validation type to ensure that the value is actually a valid email (e.g., user@mail.com). The problem, then, is that the validator doesn't know anything about a username validation type, and so when it tries to construct that method, it fails.

What you need to do is just **get rid of** your second reference to username, yielding this:

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'username' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please post your validation rules. This can either you controller code (i.e. from `$this->validate` or your form request class.

Alternatively, if you're using the default Laravel auth scaffolding, please post the contents of your registration controller (RegisterController).

Finally, do rule out the obvious (sorry), does your database definitly have a column in the `users` table titled `username`? For example, have you followed a guiode such as http://techiescircle.com/add-extra-fields-laravel-5-registration-form/ to add a new field to the users table?

It appears you're incorrectly attempting to run a validation rule that doesn't yet exist.

Comment: yes i have used the default laravel auth scaffolding,but i have username column in the user table

Comment: Can youverify that running a raw SQL query, including your new column, inserts a new user. Please post your validation rules. This can either you controller code i.e. from $this->validate or a form request class.

Answer (score 0):

```
   protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'username' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
    ]);
}



This is the issue

Right

   'username' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],



wrong
   'username' => ['required', 'string','username', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.